# How can I rotate the elements and only show 4 of them?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to code a rotating box which shows all members of a team. In total there are 6 members, but the box should display only 4 members. With *next* and *prev* arrows visitors should be able to see the other members.

My current solution makes all div.member invisible by default. Then it sets 4 global variables in javascript (`display1-4`) and assigns numbers to them (`1-4`). With each *next*-click, each display-variable increments by 1, and if higher than 6, it begins with 1 again - respectively with *prev*. This part works. Here's a demo page (I wanted to make a JSFiddle but it didn't work, alternatively you can see the page [here](http://test.mehl.mx/slide.html):

```js
// initial setting slider.js
      var display1 = 0;
      var display2 = 1;
      var display3 = 2;
      var display4 = 3;
      var maxno = 6;  // number of elements

      function ChangeSlide(direction) {
        if (direction == 'next') {  // arrow right
          display1 = display1 + 1;
          display2 = display2 + 1;
          display3 = display3 + 1;
          display4 = display4 + 1;
        } else {    // arrow left
          display1 = display1 - 1;
          display2 = display2 - 1;
          display3 = display3 - 1;
          display4 = display4 - 1;
        }

        // next gets higher than maxno
        if (display1 > maxno) {
          display1 = display1 - maxno;
        } else if (display2 > maxno) {
          display2 = display2 - maxno;
        } else if (display3 > maxno) {
          display3 = display3 - maxno;
        } else if (display4 > maxno) {
          display4 = display4 - maxno;
        }

        // prev gets lower than 1
        if (display1 < 1) {
          display1 = display1 + maxno;
        } else if (display2 < 1) {
          display2 = display2 + maxno;
        } else if (display3 < 1) {
          display3 = display3 + maxno;
        } else if (display4 < 1) {
          display4 = display4 + maxno;
        }

        // Make all existing IDs invisible
        document.getElementById('slide1').style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('slide2').style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('slide3').style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('slide4').style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('slide5').style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('slide6').style.display = 'none';

        // Make specified ID visible again
        document.getElementById('slide' + display1).style.display = 'inline-block';
        document.getElementById('slide' + display2).style.display = 'inline-block';
        document.getElementById('slide' + display3).style.display = 'inline-block';
        document.getElementById('slide' + display4).style.display = 'inline-block';
      }

ChangeSlide('next');
```

```css
.member {
      display: none;
      width: 100px;background: #FF0000;box-sizing: border-box;
    }
```

```html
<p><a onclick="ChangeSlide('prev')">PREV</a> -- <a onclick="ChangeSlide('next')">NEXT</a></p>

<div class="teambox">
  <div class="member" id="slide1"><span>Member 1</span></div>
  <div class="member" id="slide2"><span>Member 2</span></div>
  <div class="member" id="slide3"><span>Member 3</span></div>
  <div class="member" id="slide4"><span>Member 4</span></div>
  <div class="member" id="slide5"><span>Member 5</span></div>
  <div class="member" id="slide6"><span>Member 6</span></div>
</div>
```

But there is a logic mistake: if I click three times on *next* it should show the members in this order:

`4, 5, 6, 1`

Instead it shows them like this

`1, 4, 5, 6`

Similar logical flaws happen when sliding back.

My idea was to swap the child elements accordingly, one approach was

```
// move first child element (team member) to the last position 
var list = document.querySelector(".teambox");
list.appendChild(list.firstElementChild);
```

This messes the whole order much more, especially because I don't have a solution which does it the same way the other way round.

I would be glad if there was a solution without heavy frameworks like jQuery. Thank you in advance!

Comment: did my answer help? Is something missing?

Comment: @winner_joiner Looks very good so far, thank you! I will just have to test whether it works with the mobile design of my page (the 4 "members" break into two rows if the screen is small). I am currently away from my work place and will test and comment tomorrow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a efficient and small Solution, without external libraries.
*(I tried to stay as close to your code as possible)*

**Some Background to the Solution**

- Hidding the member is achieved through the css `overflow:hidden;` of the parent container css-class `teambox`. (Width was set to four times the member width)
- the cylce is done with the `insertBefore` command, which moves the nodes

```js
    // Helper Constant so that the Code can be read/understund "better"
    const AFTER_THE_LAST_ELEMENT = null; 

    function changeSlide(direction) {
      var elementToMove;
      var elements = document.querySelectorAll(".member"); 
      var parentNode = elements[0].parentNode;
      var firstElement = elements[0];
      var lastElement = elements[elements.length-1];
      
      if(direction === "next"){
        elementToMove = firstElement;
        insertBefore = AFTER_THE_LAST_ELEMENT;
      }else{
        elementToMove = lastElement;
        insertBefore = firstElement;
      }
      parentNode.insertBefore(elementToMove, insertBefore);
    }
```

```css
.member {
  width: 100px;
  background: #FF0000;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  float:left;
  height:25px;
}

.teambox{
  width:400px;
  border:solid 1px black;
  overflow:hidden;
  height:22px;
}
```

```html
<p><a onclick="changeSlide('prev')">PREV</a> -- <a onclick="changeSlide('next')">NEXT</a></p>

<div class="teambox">
  <div class="member" id="slide1"><span>Member 1</span></div>
  <div class="member" id="slide2"><span>Member 2</span></div>
  <div class="member" id="slide3"><span>Member 3</span></div>
  <div class="member" id="slide4"><span>Member 4</span></div>
  <div class="member" id="slide5"><span>Member 5</span></div>
  <div class="member" id="slide6"><span>Member 6</span></div>
</div>

<!--  tested won win7 with chrome 51+ and IE10 -->
```

**Short Explanation**

> **`document.querySelectorAll(".member")`** returns all matches as Array
> **`elements[elements.length-1]`** selects last element from Array
> **`elements[0].parentNode`** is the `parentNode` of the selected Element, needed to remove the specific element
> **`parentNode.insertBefore(lastElement, firstElement)`** inserts `lastElement` before  the current first element. if the first Parameter is `null` the element will be appened. See [MDN Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/Node/insertBefore) for Details

Comment: Thanks a lot! Your approach for rotating the elements was the best and it helped me solving the issue to the utmost satisfaction. 

However, I extended your solution since it didn't work with the design of my page. So I extended your Javascript with some lines to also hide all elements after the fourth, similar to the approach I had in my initial question. You can see the result [here](https://www.klartext-spd-bayern.eu/). Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

You have plenty of slider components available that don't have any dependencies.

Take a look at http://meandmax.github.io/lory/

You will need to modify your html structure a bit like this

```
<div class="slider js_slider">
  <div class="frame js_frame">
    <ul class="slides js_slides">
      <li class="js_slide" id="slide1"><span>Member 1</span></li>
      <li class="js_slide" id="slide2"><span>Member 2</span></li>
      <li class="js_slide" id="slide3"><span>Member 3</span></li>
      <li class="js_slide" id="slide4"><span>Member 4</span></li>
      <li class="js_slide" id="slide5"><span>Member 5</span></li>
      <li class="js_slide" id="slide6"><span>Member 6</span></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

and add this to your js file

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    var slider = document.querySelector('.js_slider');

    lory(slider, {
        rewind: true
    });
});
```

Note that you'll need some css also, take a look at the link above.

Comment: just replace span element with img